# What would be a good practice on investigating an existing Snowflake instance, using DBT?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt, snowflake-schema

1. With all the DBT and Snowflake pieces (i.e. resources, credentials, environments, etc), in place, installed, configured and properly running and
2. Following DBT best practices and DBT CLI framework,

how would I start a new DBT project to actually investigate the raw structures, existent views and relationships, in order to decide about the transformation layer that is possible to be created (i.e. new modules, new views, new relations and etc)?

For example, I`ve created a project, as in: "dbt-init investigation" and now, what sort of commands are available that could improve my understanding and writing of the transformation layer?

Commands, which would improve my visibility about the datamodel(s)/structure(s) available?

Best wishes,
I

Answer (score 0):

**There are no such commands in dbt**.

If you have an initialized dbt project, a Snowflake instance, a working connection between the two, as well as having a basic understanding of dbt best practices, then you would hopefully have at least the feeling that **dbt is not a discovery tool for your raw tables.**

> how would I start a new DBT project to actually investigate the raw structures, existent views and relationships [...]?

Looking at the [dbt Command Reference](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-commands), **no commands are available to help you explore raw structures**. Sure, you can define your sources in dbt and explore from there, but it's easier to just start writing some SQL in your data warehouse. You'll need to get down and dirty with the warehouse anyway, to even know which tables, views, etc. you have.

> what sort of commands are available that could improve my understanding and writing of the transformation layer?

**Again, no such commands**. I'm not sure if I interpret your question correctly, but are you looking for "educational dbt commands" or are books, blogs, tutorials, etc. about data transformation actually what you need?

dbt best practices (if you follow the docs) provide you with a fairly good idea about how to create your models, moving from source and staging tables through intermediate models, finally to marts that fan out to provide data to end users. There's plenty of nuance beyond that to discover as well as quite a few [dbt packages](https://hub.getdbt.com/) that are very useful to augment your projects, but those can be learned more research in the fields of data and analytics engineering, transformation, SQL, etc.